# JavaScript: Списки и ключи

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне из такого списка:

```
from [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'one', description: 'number one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two', description: 'number two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three', description: 'number three' }
]
```

Получить такой?

```
to { 
    1: { name: 'one', description: 'number one' },
    2: { name: 'two', description: 'number two' },
    3: { name: 'three', description: 'number three' }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var arr = [ 
    { id: 1, name: 'one', description: 'number one' },
    { id: 2, name: 'two', description: 'number two' },
    { id: 3, name: 'three', description: 'number three' }
];

var result = {};

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result[arr[i].id] = arr[i];
    delete arr[i].id;
}

console.log(result);
```